# DataGridView Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a webservice which populates my `DataGridView` using a couple of webmethods.

Without this code everything works great but I need the picture to change depending on the row selected and the name of the picture will be in a static column that will not change.

What I am trying to do is, in my webmethod, send it a picture name equal to `picture1.jpg`.

In the windows application I am using this code:

```
int i;
i = memdataGV.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
var pictext = memdataGV.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\\Pictures\\" + pictext;
```

When the `DataGridView` first populates everything works fine but when I click on one of my button events it throws an exception on the following line:

```
var pictext = memdataGV.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

> NullReferenceException was unhandled

I tried to debug the code and I added the `if` statement to the top however does not seem to fix it.

Comment: Are you picking just one row at a time? Or multiple?

Comment: one row at a time multiple is disabled

Comment: i tried to add   if (memdataGV.SelectedRows.Count > 0) to the top but that does not seem to help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out for some reason the index 5 was returning null and there was a value in the cell. So I did code to grab the value by the column name which found the value and is working

```
 string pictext = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["PHOTOID"].Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Three possibilities:

1. `i` has an incorrect value (-1, for example)
2. `Value` at Cells[5] is `NULL` so when you call `ToString()` blows up.
3. `Cells[5]` does not exist. I.E. maybe it's another index, like 4, for example. The index is zero-based, remember.

Based on your comment, change your line to:

```
var pictext = memdataGV.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value==null?string.empty:memdataGV.Rows[i].Cells[5].V‌​alue.ToString();
```

Comment: I set it to 4 like you said it does not error out but the picture name is in cell 5. When I click the button the only thing it does is add 3 rows to the back of the datagridview but the picture name stays in cell 5

Comment: also if I leave 5 as the index number and take off the .ToString it does not blow up like you said so you are spot on however how do I fix this cause when I take off the ToString the pictures dont show up any longer when i select a new row

Comment: @JawaidAkhtar I am not saying you should change `Cells[5]` to `Cells[4]`, I am just suggesting that you should verify that it is indeed the index you should use. You are the only one who can know for sure. If removing ToString() fixes the issue then do this instead: `var pictext = memdataGV.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value==null?string.empty:memdataGV.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();`

Comment: I am debugging it now not sure if this matters but since i have the C:\\Pictures\\" it is making the picture imagelocation C:\\Pictures\\Name.jpg will that still work the same as if it is c:\pictures\name.jpg

Comment: Thanks for all your help You pointed me in the right direction and it does not crash any longer will take it from here and try to figure the rest out. Thanks again